# What is this IC for motor driver?

Tags: integrated-circuit, dimmer

I have a 220 V motor driver and I think it is a dimmer from its bt138 TRIAC (it goes to a 220-24 transformer and then to the motor) and its IC surface is erased and expunged and I don't know its number. Does anyone know what this could be?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Trans? Transformer? Transistor? Transimpedance amplifier?

Comment:  that is transformer, i said its voltage, 220 to 24

Comment: thanks to winny for his edition